# How do I allow #PCDATA without forcing it and how do I deny #PCDATA?

Tags: xml, dtd

I would like to get an xml structor like:

```
<root>
    allow<back>no#PCDATA</back>
    allow<front>allow#PCDATA</front>
</root>
```

I have:

```
<!ELEMENT root (back?,front?)>
<!ELEMENT back (js*)>
<!ELEMENT front (para*)>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. If necessary, provide more example XML data of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You really haven't made it clear what structures you want to allow and what you want to disallow. Where do the element names `js` and `para` come into it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XML DTDs, the best you can get is

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ELEMENT root (#PCDATA|back|front)*>
  <!ELEMENT back (js*)>
  <!ELEMENT front (#PCDATA|para)*>
]>
<root>
  allow<back><!-- no#PCDATA --></back>
  allow<front>allow#PCDATA</front>
</root>
```

since XML DTDs places restrictions on how the `#PCDATA` content token can be used; namely, that it has to be part of a choice group (specifically, it must be the first part of a group of elements separated by the `|` connector) according to the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).

You can check this example using Libxml2 (the `xmllint --valid` command line utility).

SGML, on the other hand, on which XML is based, and of which XML DTD is designed to be a subset, doesn't have this restriction and allows `#PCDATA` to occur multiple times:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!-- NOTE: this is SGML not XML -->
  <!ELEMENT root - - (#PCDATA,((back,#PCDATA,front?)|(front?)))>
  <!ELEMENT back - - (js*)>
  <!ELEMENT front - - (#PCDATA|para)*>
]>
<root>
  allow<back><!-- no#PCDATA --></back>
  allow<front>allow#PCDATA</front></root>
```

You can check these SGML examples using OpenSP (the `osgmlnorm` command line utility) or sgmljs (the `sgmlproc` command line utility). However, there are restrictions with SGML in this context as well:

- you will have noticed that the `</root>` end-element tag is put at the end of the line; this is because SGML would interpret a newline as character data unless it occurs after a line containing only a single element with start- and end-element tags in which case it considers that newline as solely for formatting purposes
- a content model such as `(#PCDATA,back?,#PCDATA,front?)` isn't unambiguous and thus disallowed because if the optional `back` element isn't present, text content could be attributed to either of the two `#PCDATA` tokens